# How to pass a reference value to \listadd from package etoolbox, so that one can retrieve it with the value it had at the time it was input?

Tags: cross-referencing, etoolbox

How to pass a reference value, such as `\thesection`, to `\listadd` from package `etoolbox`, so that one can retrieve it with the value it had at the time it was input?

The following MWE illustrates that issue:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\begin{document}

\section{Section 1}

\listadd{\mylist}{Section 1 = Section \thesection}
Section 1 = Section \thesection

\section{Section 2}

Section 2 = Section \thesection

\newcounter{mycounter}
\setcounter{mycounter}{0}

Counter = \themycounter

\forcsvlist{\listadd{\mylist}}{Section 2 = Section \thesection,Counter = \themycounter}
\setcounter{mycounter}{10}

\section{Section 3}

\newcommand{\printlist}[1]{%
  #1
  
}%

%% Print \mylist items
\forlistloop{\printlist}{\mylist}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: You can use `\listeadd`, the `e` stands for `expanded`.

Comment: Thanks, please post it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/etoolbox/etoolbox.pdf) of etoolbox describes the various versions of `\listadd` that deal with expansion and scope (page 29, section 3.7.2 Internal Lists):

> - `\listgadd{listmacro}{item}` Similar to `\listadd` except that the
>   assignment is global.
> - `\listeadd{listmacro}{item}` Similar to
>   `\listadd` except that the `item` is expanded at definition-time. Only
>   the new `item` is expanded, the `listmacro` is not. If the expanded
>   `item` is blank, it is not added to the list.
> - `\listxadd{listmacro}{item}` Similar to `\listeadd` except that the
>   assignment is global.

So in this case the macro `\listeadd` can be used to expand the contents when the item is added.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\begin{document}

\section{Section 1}

\listeadd{\mylist}{Section 1 = Section \thesection}
Section 1 = Section \thesection

\section{Section 2}

Section 2 = Section \thesection

\newcounter{mycounter}
\setcounter{mycounter}{0}

Counter = \themycounter

\forcsvlist{\listeadd{\mylist}}{Section 2 = Section \thesection,Counter = \themycounter}
\setcounter{mycounter}{10}

\section{Section 3}

\newcommand{\printlist}[1]{%
  #1
  
}%

%% Print \mylist items
\forlistloop{\printlist}{\mylist}

\end{document}
```

Result:
[image]